# Block devices sda, sdb, sdc. What comes after sdz?

Tags: kernel, hard-drive

My block devices are named `sda`, `sdb` and so on.

What happens when I get to `sdz`? Is the next one going to be called `sdaa`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. The kernel will continue to assign names in the form of `sdaa`, `sdab` and so on. There may be [a bug preventing it from going beyond `sdzzz`](http://marc.info/?l=linux-scsi&m=128499962624675&w=2), but [in theory, it's going to continue forever](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/sd.c?h=v2.6.37#n2262) (that is up to 18278 due to data type limitations).

<sub>my thanks to Rinzwind for providing the links</sub>

Comment: Not a problem :) Good answer!

Comment: small problem: 18278 is virtio-blk. currently sata is expected (untested) to do 29 z's.

Answer (score 4):

### After `sda`➡`sdz` comes `sdaa`➡`sdaz`, etc.

The first link in the accepted answer (from 2011) is broken. Here is a new link (also from 2011) containing a good write-up: [How are Linux drives named beyond drive 26?](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/how-are-linux-drives-named-beyond-drive-26-devsdz/).

To summarize the main point in the link (slightly revised and reformatted):

```
Drive # - Name
1       - sda
26      - sdz
27      - sdaa
28      - sdab
52      - sdaz
53      - sdba
54      - sdbb
702     - sdzz
703     - sdaaa
704     - sdaab
18278   - sdzzz
```

Needless to say Linux is well positioned for expansion of drives.

Comment: I fixed the link. The rest of the answer could be just an edit to the other post.